# Why this code does not identify the class of an IP in some cases?

Tags: python, ip-address, python-ipaddress

I wrote the following Python code that is mean to classify whether an IP is valid, if valid then to what class it belongs and whether it is private:

```
from ipaddress import IPv4Address, IPv4Network, ip_address
import sys

try:
    ip = ip_address(sys.argv[1])
    print(f"{ip} is a correct IP{ip.version} address.")
    if ip_address(ip).is_private:
            print("It is a private IP.")
    classA = IPv4Network(("10.0.0.0", "255.0.0.0")) 
    classB = IPv4Network(("172.16.0.0", "255.240.0.0"))
    classC = IPv4Network(("192.168.0.0", "255.255.0.0")) 
    if ip in classA:
        print(f"{ip} is a correct class A IP{ip.version} address.")
        if ip_address(ip).is_private:
            print("It is a private IP.")
    elif ip in classB:
        print(f"{ip} is a correct class B IP{ip.version} address.")
        if ip_address(ip).is_private:
            print("It is a private IP.")
    elif ip in classC:
        print(f"{ip} is a correct class C IP{ip.version} address.") 
        if ip_address(ip).is_private:
            print("It is a private IP.")
except ValueError:
    print(f'address/netmask is invalid: {sys.argv[1]}')
except:
    print(f'Usage : {sys.argv[0]}  ip')
```

I assumed [that the range of](https://learning.edx.org/course/course-v1:LinuxFoundationX+LFS101x+2T2021/block-v1:LinuxFoundationX+LFS101x+2T2021+type@sequential+block@7079eecfff7642b7857d4c3d5ae010a5/block-v1:LinuxFoundationX+LFS101x+2T2021+type@vertical+block@7d1a10a6a8f845b68c1358a1e7db01a2) class A is from `1.0.0.0` to `127.255.255.255`, of class B is from `128.0.0.0` to `191.255.255.255`, and of class C is from `192.0.0.0` to `223.255.255.255`.
When given `141.68.27.102` it does not
classify the class as B (although [the answer to this cisco lab does](https://developer.cisco.com/learning/lab/networking-103-IP-addresses/step/4)), why so?
When given `192.12.13.14` it does not
classify the class as C (although [the answer to this cisco lab does](https://developer.cisco.com/learning/lab/networking-103-IP-addresses/step/4)), why so?

Comment: Get rid of that bare `except:` handler for one -- you'll never know what actual errors occur within that try block.

Comment: Why is `if ip_address(ip).is_private` repeated? Same for `f"... IP{ip.version} address."`

Comment: @wjandrea For no good reason, but that's beside OP's point :)

Comment: `172.32.255.255` is in `172.32.0.0/12` not `172.16.0.0/12` which ends at `172.31.255.255`. Equally `192.168.0.0/16` will never include `192.12.*`, and `141.68.*` isn't a special 'private' range at all (and doesn't overlap with any of your specified class ranges).

Comment: The three `IPv4Network` objects you create contain *only* the private addresses in each class, not the entire class (not that the concept of "class" is particularly meaningful these days).  For example, your `classC` covers only 192.168.x.y; your example of 192.12.13.14 is obviously not in that range.

Comment: @wjandrea For no good reason. Earlier I was debuggin some other thing and I forgot to remove it. It should not be repeated, apologies for the clutter.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The short answer is that "because those IPs don't belong in the classes as you've defined them".

This somewhat simplified rework of your program prints out the classes first, so you can see how you've defined them... and why they don't seem to properly match.

```
from ipaddress import IPv4Network, ip_address

classes = {
    "A": IPv4Network(("10.0.0.0", "255.0.0.0")),
    "B": IPv4Network(("172.16.0.0", "255.240.0.0")),
    "C": IPv4Network(("192.168.0.0", "255.255.0.0")),
}


def describe_ip(ip_str):
    ip = ip_address(ip_str)
    for class_name, network in classes.items():
        if ip in network:
            print(f"{ip} is a correct class {class_name} IP{ip.version} address.")
            break
    else:
        print(f"{ip} does not belong in any of the classes defined.")


print(classes)
describe_ip("172.32.255.255")
describe_ip("141.68.27.102")
describe_ip("192.12.13.14")
describe_ip("172.16.255.255")
```

The output is something like (where the last line proves that 172.16. addresses do match your B class definition).

```
{'A': IPv4Network('10.0.0.0/8'), 'B': IPv4Network('172.16.0.0/12'), 'C': IPv4Network('192.168.0.0/16')}
172.32.255.255 does not belong in any of the classes defined.
141.68.27.102 does not belong in any of the classes defined.
192.12.13.14 does not belong in any of the classes defined.
172.16.255.255 is a correct class B IP4 address.
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer. Why is `172.32.255.255` not a class B address? (assuming the range of the class: `128.0.0.0` to `191.255.255.255`). I added to my question a reference to a Cisco lab in which it is stated that `192.12.13.14` belongs to class C (I lean on agreeing with them as I assume the range `192.0.0.0` to `223.255.255.255`). You must have good reasons for your answer - do you apply different ranges than the ones adduced by me? I already modified the question.

Comment: The IP range definitions in my answers are yours, I haven't changed them. I can't access the Cisco links without logging in, so I don't know how they've defined those ranges.